# How to dynamically create a dependent select list using one recursive function in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, recursion

The [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2icJv.png) shows the list structure that needs to be created. Using a recursive function it could be reused for *n* number of options. How can it be done?

Here is my Javascript code and below the HTML that I wrote:

```js
        var gender = ['male', 'female'];
        
        var male = {
            hair: ["Facial hair preferred?","Hair","No Hair"],
    
            complexion: ["Preferred Complexion?","Pale","Dark"],
    
            build: ["Build Type?","Strong","Weak"]
        }

        //Female Object
        var female = {
            hair: ["Hair Color?","Blonde","Brunette"],
    
            height: ["Preferred Height?","Tall","Short"],
    
            eyes: ["Preferred Eyes?","Green","Blue"]
        }
        
        function build(sel){
            var selValue = sel;
            if(selValue == gender[0]){
                //console.log('male');
                
                var sEle = document.createElement('select');
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sEle);
                
                for(var i=0; i<male.hair.length; ++i){
                    var oEle = document.createElement('option');
                
                    if(i == 0){
                        oEle.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                        oEle.setAttribute('selected','selected');
                    }
                    
                var optionText = document.createTextNode(male.hair[i]);
                oEle.appendChild(optionText);
                document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1].appendChild(oEle);
                }
            }else{
                //console.log('female');
                var sEle = document.createElement('select');
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sEle);
                
                for(var i=0; i<female.hair.length; ++i){
                    var oEle = document.createElement('option');
                    
                    if(i == 0){
                        oEle.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
                        oEle.setAttribute('selected','selected');
                }
                    
                var optionText = document.createTextNode(female.hair[i]);
                oEle.appendChild(optionText);
                document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1].appendChild(oEle);
            }
        }
    
        }
```

```html
<body>
    
    <h4>Select Sex </h4>
    <select name="sel1" id="sel1" onchange="build(this.value)">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Sex</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    
    
    
</body>
```

However I am stuck and unable to create any more. Moreover I am not able to create a recursive function that I can reuse for any data.

Comment: why `complexion` is liable to `hair` (the same with other categories)?. They should be independent categories

Comment: Yes, they are independent categories. I just happened to draw it like that. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with tree hierarchy like this:

```js
function Node(msg, treeChildNodes)
{
  var _node = this;
  this.msg = msg;
  this.treeChildNodes = treeChildNodes;
  
  this.completed = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    this.disabled = true;
    
    if (_node.treeChildNodes[this.value])
      _node.treeChildNodes[this.value].renderTo(_node.container);
    else
    {
      console.log('the leaf! end test');
      $("<button/>").text('Finish test').appendTo(_node.container);
    }
  };
  
  this.renderTo = function(container) {
    _node.container = container;
    $("<p/>").text(_node.msg).appendTo(container);
    var $select = $("<select/>").appendTo(container).change(this.completed);
    
    $("<option/>").text("Not selected...").appendTo($select);
    for (var childKey in this.treeChildNodes)
    {
        $("<option/>").text(childKey).appendTo($select);
    }
  };
}

var tree = new Node('Men or Women?', {
    'M': new Node('Facial hair?', {
      'Hair': new Node('Complexion', {
        'D': null,
        'L': null
      }),
      'No Hair': new Node('Build', {
        'B': null,
        'S': null
      })                 
    })
  });
      
tree.renderTo('body');
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I haven't implemented women side of this tree, it is just an example, you can easily do it yourself :)

By the way, with this approach, your tree should not actually be a tree. For example, your test questions can split once, and then flock back into a single branch.

Comment: I am not that familiar with object oriented JS so, I am hoping to get an answer on how to do it using a recursive function that can dynamically create select and option elements without hard coding so that the code can be re-used no matter how many arrays of data are added. Also, when there is a change in selecting options from one of the select lists the child node created for that should be removed and a new one should be created with the relevant array options.